# How does dual nature of matter affect collision at the quantum level?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, collision, superposition, wave-particle-duality

I have a question suppose having two fundamental particles collide which each other at the quantum scale , then what will the collision behave as

Will the particle nature be dominant and make sure to conserve momentum as we see in macroscopic objects

or

Will the wave nature be dominant and the principle of superposition is applied ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a sense both particle and wave properties come in to play. So, it is not an either-or scenario.

The interaction of fields at the quantum level is in effect the direct manifestation of the quantum nature of such fields. During the interaction, each field exchanges a quantum of energy-momentum. In this sense, one can think of the fields in terms of their particle nature. However, the exchange allows all possible outcomes that satisfy the requirements of energy-momentum conservation. Therefore, the result is a superposition of all such outcomes. In this sense, the wave properties are revealed.

However, "waves" in the quantum context is not like waves in classical theories. They could be in simple cases, but the kind of state produced by interactions consists of multiple entities (I am avoid the word "particles" here) in superposition, which is not something you get in classical scenarios. One can write down the expression for the wave function of such a state, but it would not look like a classical wave.

Comment: what I am trying to get from the answer is both are expected to happen ,  but another question arises from this for me at the last line it is indirectly related to wave nature but i thought they are in form of waves as like water/sound waves that is how i understood debroglie wavelength too the wavelength of those waves , but that is not revealed here the wave nature is brought upon indirectly what am i missing here

Comment: I added some explanation. If you prefer a concrete example, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Quantum mechanics textbooks will derive collision cross sections (how "big" is the atom when it comes to collisions with other atoms) using quantum mechanics. And they will state that this calculation is more accurate than a classical one treating the particles as points with forces between eachother. Particularly it's more accurate for things like calculating how quickly a gas comes to equilibrium due to collisions.

But why? Ultimately, it comes down to asking "are particle's wave functions typically much bigger than the distance between the two particles, or typically much smaller, such that they behave like well localized point particles." The former is usually the case. Particles with mass have their wavefunctions grow over time. From the research I've done in the past, people typically estimate that a typical particle in a gas has a wave function that is about the "mean free path" (the distance between collisions). So when a collision happens, the two colliding particles can be well approximated by giant quantum mechanical plane waves. This is why quantum mechanical calculations of collision cross sections are accurate.

P.S. the conservation of momentum is also a property of quantum mechanics (in a kind of different way).